# how to code a progress bar

Tags: javascript

I'm building a youtube player with custom controls using the youtube api:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=chromeless&playerVersion=as3

I've got the play/pause/skip buttons all done but I've got to create a progress bar and I can't think how to do it. I've never programmed a progress bar before. I can access the total video time and also poll the current play time using setinterval...so every 250ms for example I can poll to find out the videos current position.

My question is how do I make use of that data to create a progress bar? I'm thinking of a div that I could manipulate in width to show video progress. My problem is how do i make use of the data (total video duration and current time) to decide when and how much to increase the width of this div.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula to calculate the size of your progress-bar is very basic: `$download_size / $download_progress * $max_progressbar_width`. You just need to make sure that both download sizes use the same units to get a correct proportion.

Comment: So that would be total_video_duration / current_time * the_width_of_progress_bar? ----and just make sure that i'm only dealing with numbers in the calculations.